# problems with wifi rtl8723be

Tags: wifi

I recently install elementary and I found that I can't connect to any network, I looked for in Google and it's a problem with drivers. If you know about please answer me, please.

Comment: Is it a HP laptop?

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsusb` and `rfkill list all`?

Comment: If you are using Loki, see http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/11128/4188

Answer (score 1):

You may try compiling this drivers from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new like this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make clean
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hi I input all the commands and still not working and yes is a hp laptop and the main problem is I need to be near to the router and sometimes the signal get down. Thanks for all your answers