# No wifi access points with rtl8723be

Tags: wifi

Just newly installed Elemntary OS Loki, I see wifi settings, but no any access points visible. When I go to windows 10, all wifi networks are in the list.
My wifi adapter is Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn, on my HP machine.
Somehow it seems that on Elementary OS wifi signal is weaker, than on windows 10. What might be a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newbie Q re: a RTL8723BE wifi fix, and how to install one](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9806/newbie-q-re-a-rtl8723be-wifi-fix-and-how-to-install-one)

Comment: I've same issue wiht wifi controller RTW_PCI does'nt work and no visible on elementary OS Hera 5.1. It's possible install manualy ? Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with HP using one antenna wire on a wireless chip with 2 antenna connections.  Since you see no wireless AP's we can just do the following in terminal.

First we will unload the module and reload it using the module parameter to try one option for the antenna

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Then we can check to see if any AP's are found with

```
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
```

Then we can try the other antenna option and compare results

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
```

If the `ant_sel=1` had better results then

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723beant.conf
```

If `ant_sel=2` was the better option

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723beant.conf
```